# Построить гистограмму в Excel на основе данных

Tags: c#, excel

хочу построить гистограмму по продажам. Есть следующий код:

```
using XL = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
private void btnXL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XL.Application XL1 = new XL.Application(); // Объявляем объект
            XL1.Workbooks.Add(); // Добавляем рабочую книгу

            // Заполнить ячейки A2 (со 2 по 6)
            XL1.ActiveSheet.Range["A2"].Value = "Март";
            XL1.ActiveSheet.Range["A3"].Value = "Апрель";
            XL1.ActiveSheet.Range["A4"].Value = "Май";
            XL1.ActiveSheet.Range["A5"].Value = "Июнь";
            XL1.ActiveSheet.Range["A6"].Value = "Июль";

            // Заполнить ячейки B2 (со 2 по 6)
            XL1.ActiveSheet.Range["B2"].Value = 150000;
            XL1.ActiveSheet.Range["B3"].Value = 225000;
            XL1.ActiveSheet.Range["B4"].Value = 56700;
            XL1.ActiveSheet.Range["B5"].Value = 280345;
            XL1.ActiveSheet.Range["B6"].Value = 500000; 

            // Добавить новую диаграмму
            XL1.Charts.Add();

            // Задаем тип графика - столбчатая диаграммма
            XL1.ActiveChart.ChartType = XL.XlChartType.xlColumnClustered;
            // Отключаем легенду и задаем имя диаграммы
            XL1.ActiveChart.HasLegend = false;
            XL1.ActiveChart.HasTitle = true;
            XL1.ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "ПРОДАЖИ ЗА ПЯТЬ МЕСЯЦЕВ";

            // Задаем подписи по оси X
            XL1.ActiveChart.Axes(XL.XlAxisType.xlCategory).HasTitle = true;
            XL1.ActiveChart.Axes(XL.XlAxisType.xlCategory).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Уровни продаж";

            // Задаем подписи по оси Y
            XL1.ActiveChart.Axes(XL.XlAxisType.xlCategory).HasTitle = true;
            XL1.ActiveChart.Axes(XL.XlAxisType.xlCategory).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Месяцы";

            // Сохраняем график в растровом файле
            XL1.ActiveChart.Export("myFile.jpg");
            XL1.Visible = true;
        }
```

По нажатию на данную кнопку возникает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто знает как это исправить или может Вы знаете другой способ построения гистограммы ?

Comment: У меня код работает. Скорее всего, проблема в самом офисе.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо.

Comment: Можете еще подсказать, если я сейчас обновлю офис, но в самом проекте уже используется microsoft object library 12.0 мне нужно будет и здесь обновить или конфликтов никаких не будет ?

Comment: Обычно при переходе на более новую версию ссылки на библиотеку старой должны продолжать работать, без необходимости их обновлять.