# Как здесь вывести гистограмму через excel?

Tags: c#

Суть программы: это шифр табличной перестановки, программа меняет строки и столбцы местами, выводит количество букв в txt файле и заносит количество букв в таблицу excel.
Как мне вывести гистограмму из количества этих самых букв?

```
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public class Program
{

    static void poisk(string stroka, int f)
    {
        // Создаём экземпляр нашего приложения
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        // Создаём экземпляр рабочий книги Excel
        Excel.Workbook workBook;
        // Создаём экземпляр листа Excel
        Excel.Worksheet workSheet;

        workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
        workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
        // Открываем созданный excel-файл
        excelApp.Visible = true;
        excelApp.UserControl = true;
        bool q = true;
        char[] Stroka2 = stroka.ToCharArray();
        string alfovit = "АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯяAaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz";
        char[] alfovit2 = alfovit.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 59; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < stroka.Length; j++)
            {

                if ((alfovit2[2 * i] == Stroka2[j]) || (alfovit2[2 * i + 1] == Stroka2[j]))
                {
                    f = f + 1;
                }
                
            }
            if (f != 0)
                if (q) Console.WriteLine("");
            if (i != 0)
            {
                workSheet.Cells[1, i] = f;
            }
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Этот символ " + alfovit2[2*i] + " встречается " + f + " раз");
                q = false;
                
            }
            f = 0;

        }
    }
        public static char[,] CreateArray(string s, int cols)
    {
        int rows = s.Length / cols + 1;
        char[,] arr = new char[rows, cols];

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            char c = s[i];
            arr[y, x] = c;

            x++;
            if (x >= cols)
            {
                x = 0;
                y++;
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }

    public static void PrintArray(char[,] arr)
    {
        int rows = arr.GetLength(0);
        int cols = arr.GetLength(1);

        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
            {
                Console.Write(arr[row, col]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public static void SwapColumns(char[,] arr, int x1, int x2)
    {
        int rows = arr.GetLength(0);
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            char c = arr[row, x1];
            arr[row, x1] = arr[row, x2];
            arr[row, x2] = c;
        }
    }

    public static void SwapRows(char[,] arr, int y1, int y2)
    {
        int cols = arr.GetLength(1);
        for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++)
        {
            char c = arr[y1, col];
            arr[y1, col] = arr[y2, col];
            arr[y2, col] = c;
        }
    }


    public static void Main()
    {

        System.IO.StreamReader sr = System.IO.File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\Danil\source\repos\4 лаба перестановка табличная\4 лаба перестановка табличная\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Лиходеев.txt");
        string otrivok = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close(); Console.WriteLine("Введите количество столбцов:");
        int l = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        char[,] arr = CreateArray(otrivok, l);

        PrintArray(arr);

        Console.WriteLine("---------");
        Random r = new Random();
        Random t = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Введите сколько раз поменять столбцы:");
        int p = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i =0;i<p ;i++ ) {
            int f = r.Next(0, p-1);
            int d = r.Next(0, p-1);
            SwapColumns(arr, f, d);
        }
        PrintArray(arr);

        Console.WriteLine("---------");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите сколько раз поменять строки:");
        int v = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < v; i++)
        {
            int f = r.Next(0, v-1);
            int d = r.Next(0, v-1);
            SwapRows(arr, f, d);
        }
        
        PrintArray(arr);
        int k = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("---------");
        Console.WriteLine("---------");
        Console.WriteLine("Частота символов в тексте:");
        poisk(otrivok, k);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.chart?view=excel-pia

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/911891/373567

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47038021/12888024

Comment: @aepot это я видел) как в моей именно программе это сделать, у меня же в цикле там всё и нужны не статичные значения, а те, которые там появятся, занесённые в переменную

Comment: Окей, что именно не получается? Цикл сделать, переменную объявить, массив создать?